# Type mismatch when tring to extract the date by calling a function in macro

Tags: macros

I am using the below code. I am getting the "Type Mismatch : Error 13" when i am trying to execute it. I tried by putting all variable type (long, double, date, string) but non of them worked out.

```
Function DefectCreateDate()

Dim j
Dim DateString
Dim CreatedDate
j = GetClm("Created Date")
i = 2
DateString = "19-03-2013  21:41:01"
DefectCreateDate = DateValue(DateString)

End Function


Sub testnewde()
Dim K
Dim j
k= 2
j = DefectCreateDate(k)
MsgBox (j)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an errant parameter 'k' being passed into DefectCreateDate; its defintion is parameterles.

Comment: Even i remove the "k" and put 2 into DefectCreateDate(2), still i am getting the same type mismatch error.

Comment: Try building up the complexity. Comment out the j = GetClm("Created Date") line as it's currently benign. Then try "February 1,2010" as the date string.

Comment: after commenting out the the  j = GetClm("Created Date"), i am getting the same error. and i can't use the ""February 1,2010" ". in the code that i am writing, I am just fetching the data using the "'DateString = Workbooks("TFS Report").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, j).Value" code..... to make it simple here i just put the value of the date string that i was getting through the DateString line.

Comment: You need to remove the argument in DefectCreateDate. On which line does the error occur?

Comment: Io have already try out this. This is fetching the error when i am executing the testnewde() subroutine.

Comment: Hum. Do you think you could edit your example in the question to simplify it? Reduce the problem to bare-bones. (I don't have Excel at home so I'm checking by inspection). Else I'll take a look on Monday.

Comment: I got the mistake. I forgot to put the argument while defining the the function. It should be as Function DefectCreateDate(a) instead of Function DefectCreateDate().

Comment: Awesome; we were all trying to tell you that!